# Autocomplate Spellcheck and Highlight in solr faceted search

Tags: django, solr, jquery-autocomplete, spell-checking, highlighting

i am using solr faceted search with direct access to its search form. but now i am having problem is doing highlighting auto completing and spell checking in templete using jquery. here is my code

in urls.py

```
url(r'^solr/$', FacetedSearchView(form_class=FacetedSearchForm, searchqueryset=sqs), name='haystack_search'),
url(r'^search/$', FacetedSearchView(form_class=FacetedSearchForm, searchqueryset=sqs1), name='haystack_search'),
```

in my search template

```
{% extends "portal/site_base.html" %}
{% load highlight %}
{% load i18n %} 
{% block hero_text %}{% trans "Search" %}{% endblock %}
{% block header %}
{% trans "Click around!" %}
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}</pre>
  <div class="span12">
     <h1>{% trans "Search" %}</h1>
  <form class=".form-search" action="." method="get">{{ form.as_table }}
  <input type="submit" value="Search" /></form><hr width="710"></div>
```

now i want to do 3 things

1. highlight
2. spellcheck
3. autocomplete

i tried many examples but unable to do so. can any one tell me how to do these in jquery. i am new to django help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is not the way to ask question. Show us what you have tried so far and what does not work. You have only shown the form not the code which is actually trying to do highlighting on the field. Also ask one question at a time. Thanks